# Is their any way to identify user updating app and user installing app for the first time in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, in-app-purchase

I'm giving an update for my existing iOS App and in this update I'm locking few existing functionalities and on In App purchase these functionalities will be unlocked.
But for existing users even if they update it should not lock the functionalities only for new users it has to happen. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do what is called "Receipt Validation."  There is a programming guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html)

Basically, you can get the purchase data of the app, and it will include the original version that was purchased.  That way, if it is below the version that you introduced the new model into then you can disable in app purchasing and just give the full functionality.

Comment: Wow, good one! Wasn't aware that you can validate the original purchase just like in-apps... +1